# delay time in the range of nano second in python on ARM

Tags: python, time, arm

I want to use of usleep() in python on ARM in range of nanosecond (ns) :

does given delay time is accurate?

if it isn't accurate what should we do for making correct delay time?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any delay function is limited by the clock period of the processor. If your processor runs at 100 MHz then the smallest unit of time you can possibly measure is 10 ns. If you are running python using system functions then the granularity is much, much bigger. If you want delay times with resolution less than 1 microsecond you should be writing your code in assembly, not a high level language.

Comment: thanks.I am using Cortex A7 .It processor runs at 1 GHz.how I do write assembly in python for ARM

Comment: Sorry, I use C so I don't know how you would do this in python.